# Return to previous uitableview row upon return Swift

Tags: uitableview, swift3

When a user returns to the UITableView from the detailViewController, I want the tableView to return to the previous position. Found a solution from [this post](https://grokswift.com/programmatic-uitableview-scrolling/), but it does not work as I have not saved the selected row.  This is where I am stuck.

```
func scrollToSelectedRow() {
    let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
    if let selectedRow = selectedRows?[0] as NSIndexPath? {
        self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: selectedRow as IndexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
    }
}
```

with

```
    scrollToSelectedRow()
```

in the viewDidAppear.

I do save the row as below to send the detail to the DetailViewController

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
{

    self.selected = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row

    return indexPath
}
```

However, not sure how to associate the two together.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is this part

```
 let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
 if let selectedRow = selectedRows?[0] as NSIndexPath? {
    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: selectedRow as IndexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
}
```

If statement is never called

Trying doing this

Declare your index path like this

```
   var selected = IndexPath(row: NSNotFound, section: NSNotFound)
```

Now in didselect class

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChatViewController")
    self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)


    self.selected = (indexPath as NSIndexPath) as IndexPath


 }
```

Call this function

```
   func scrollToSelectedRow() {

      if self.selected.row != NSNotFound
        {

         self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: self.selected as IndexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)

        }

}
```

In

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    scrollToSelectedRow()

}
```